# Show that the following sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ given by $x_1 = a \in \mathbb{R}, x_2 = b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_n = 0.5(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ is Cauchy ?
I tried by using $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|=(0.5)|x_{n+1} -x_{n}|$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Does it follow that the given sequence is cauchy ?

Comment: Welcome at MathStackExchange (MSE). In order to receive good answers, you should take your time in formulating your question. Show us what you have tried and why you are not able to complete the question. Also, use MathJax (similar to LaTeX syntax) to typeset mathematics. You can see how it can be used by clicking on edit in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>m$ and note that:
$$\begin{align*}
|x_n-x_m|&=|x_n-x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}+x_{n-2}-\dots-x_{m+1}+x_{m+1}-x_m|\\
&\leq|x_n-x_{n-1}|+|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|+\dots+|x_{m+1}-x_m|
\end{align*}$$
by triangular inequality. Can you continue from this point, using what you have found up to now?

Comment: yes.thanks now i can continue it .